# What causes Python socket error?

Tags: python, sockets, permissions

```
  File "C:\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 101, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 341, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: (10013, 'Permission denied')
```

I tried to start up the Google App Engine development server and received this error the first time I tried to run it. Any ideas? I'm new to python.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It might be possible that you are trying to run on a port the current user account does not have permission to bind to. This could be port 80 or something. Try increasing the portnumber or use a user with sufficient privileges.

Hope this helps

Comment: I wonder why the error is not "Port already in use". I kind of know the answer but I should not need to use SO to know it. :)

Comment: @Oscar if the port is in use, that is what python says ("error: (48, 'Address already in use')"). Sometimes users don't have permission to access ports below some number, which I presume is the case here.

Comment: Worked for me with port 9000. Use --port=desired-port-number argument.

Comment: If you're trying to use port 80 it will potentially raise an error because you don't have the right permissions. You must use this command "sudo dev_appserver.py --port=80 yourapp/"

Comment: Thanks! I mistyped my port.

Comment: ...or use authbind --deep

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder why the error is not "Port
>   already in use". I kind of know the
>   answer but I should not need to use SO
>   to know it. :) – Oscar Reyes May 13 at
>   19:09

The port is not in use, (in UNIX) you need to be superuser to listen on any port < 1024.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are using the default port assigned by gae sdk so you might want to ensure that it is not used by any other programs.

Answer (score 0):

run it as follow. This should work

```
python -m 8888
```

if this does not work. Try other numbers like 8080.