# socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, sockets, windows-7, compatibility, socketserver

I'm trying to create a custom TCP stack using Python 2.6.5 on Windows 7 to serve valid http page requests on port 80 locally.  But, I've run into a snag with what seems like Windows 7 tightened up security.  This code worked on Vista.

Here's my sample code:

```
import SocketServer
import struct

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        headerText = """HTTP/1.0 200 OK
                        Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
                        Content-Type: text/html
                        Content-Length: 1354"""
        bodyText = "<html><body>some page</body></html>"
        self.request.send(headerText + "\n" + bodyText)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 80
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

> **C:\python>python TestServer.py**
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "TestServer.py", line 19, in
>   
>       server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT),
>   MyTCPHandler)   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py",
>   line 400, in **init**
>       self.server_bind()   File "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py",
>   line 411, in server_bind
>       self.socket.bind(self.server_address) 
>   File "", line 1, in bind
>
> socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt
>   was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions

How exactly do I get this to work on Windows 7?

[Edit on 5/5/2010 @ 2344 PDT]  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550032/what-causes-python-socket-error) explains that the error is caused by the need for elevated / superuser privileges when accessing ports lower than 1024.  I'm going to try using a higher port number to see if that works.  However, I still would like to know why my local admin account can't access port 80.

Comment: Your local admin account may not be able to bind to port 80 because there is already another process (server) bound to it. `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` will quickly show you if port 80 is already bound.

Comment: @msw That should give a different error.

Comment: @msw/everybody note that [a telnet client isn't installed on Win7 by default.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On Windows Vista/7, with UAC, administrator accounts run programs in unprivileged mode by default.

Programs must prompt for administrator access before they run as administrator, with the ever-so-familiar UAC dialog. Since Python scripts aren't directly executable, there's no "Run as Administrator" context menu option.

It's possible to use `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()` to detect whether the script has admin access, and [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the 'runas' verb on python.exe, with sys.argv[0] as a parameter to prompt the UAC dialog if needed.

Comment: make sure you `import ctypes` before running `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()`

Answer (score 62):

I just encountered the same issue, my system is Win7. just use the command on terminal like: netstat -na|findstr port, you will see the port has been used. So if you want to start the server without this message, you can change other port that not been used.

Comment: This was the case for me on Win8

Comment: i was also able to resolve this error by changing the application port in Win8

Comment: Or stop/change the process that is using the other port.  Many ways to find which process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: added python.exe and can now run my code in windows powershell. thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Try to run the server at a different port. Worked for me:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:7000
```

Explanation:

as mentioned on Django documentation:

**If you run this script as a user with normal privileges (recommended), you might not have access to start a port on a low port number. Low port numbers are reserved for the superuser (root).**

This server uses the WSGI application object specified by the WSGI_APPLICATION setting.

DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Comment: @Armali I hope this provides a plausible explanation

Answer (score 19):

For me it was complaining like that on Windows 7 x64 when I had another process already listening on that same port.

It is possible to see currently occupied (bound) ports by running

```
netstat -ban
```

Answer (score 12):

McAfee was blocking it for me. I had to allow the program in the access protection rules

1. Open VirusScan
2. Right click on Access Protection and choose Properties
3. Click on "Anti-virus Standard Protection"
4. Select rule "Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail" and click edit
5. Add the application to the Processes to exclude list and click OK

See http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/we-are-unable-send-your-email-caused-mcafee

Comment: Thanks man saved my life i was stuck for past 2 days done lot of changes but worked from this solution

Answer (score 9):

Your local port is using by another app. I faced the same problem!
You can try the following step:

1. Go to command line and run it as administrator!
2. Type:

   ```
   netstat -ano | find ":5000"
   => TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4032
      TCP    [::]:5000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4032
   ```
3. Type:

   ```
   TASKKILL /F /PID 4032
   ```

   > => SUCCESS: The process with PID 4032 has been terminated.

*Note: My 5000 local port was listing by PID 4032. You should give yours!*

Comment: might be a good idea to see what app is using the port before blindly killing the process id. For that see `pslist` from SysInternals (and `pskill`).

Answer (score 8):

**socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

Got this with **flask** :

Means that the port you're trying to bind to, **is already in used by another service or process** :
got a hint on this in my code developed on Eclipse / windows :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     # Check the System Type before to decide to bind
     # If the system is a Linux machine -:) 
     if platform.system() == "Linux":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, debug=True)
     # If the system is a windows /!\ Change  /!\ the   /!\ Port
     elif platform.system() == "Windows":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=50000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/socket-10013-error-when-trying-to-connect-some/2cc71cb6-24b2-4b63-8f60-32bb444eb8fd?auth=1

Answer (score 4):

Just run on ports above 1024 , anything below is privileged, its the same deal with Linux, i use 5000 for example on wins without any UAC priv escalation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution to your problem..this error occurs either due to another process or bunch of processes running on the port which you are trying to run you app on.
**Open cmd as an admin**
This may also occure if you have setup your server as a SERVICE and the service breaks.
Give below command

```bash
netstat -ano | findstr portNo
```

you'll be able to see list of active task on that port.
you can close all unnecessary task by using

```bash
taskkill /pid taskNo /F
```

once done restart your server.

Answer (score 3):

It Seems the Port 80 is already in use. Try to Use some other Port which is not in use by any other application in your System.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this on Windows 10 by editing an outbound firewall rule.
Right click "allow" on rule "Block network access for R local user accounts in SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER"

[image: from Windows 10 Firewall - Outbound rules- this is what was blocking my instance]

Screenshot from Windows 10 Firewall - Outbound rules- this is what was blocking my instance

Answer (score 2):

I had to allow ..\python27\python.exe in windows firewall.  I don't need to do this on WinXP or Win8.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different port than 80

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is port number used by another application.So you can change the port number to unused one as shown below.

In windows you can view the used port numbers used by different apps in windows task manager.

```py
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:portnumber
Ex: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: "In windows you can view the used port numbers used by different apps in windows task manager."  I can't see them.  Please double check this and provide instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I just found in my case Kaspersky Internet Security 2019 Firewall was blocking net access for python. Disabling firewall working smoothly. Or adding a exception rules for python app and all file extension with *.py will also work.

Comment: could you please show more specific info, and show me how to add more rule? Because I checked, the python is truthed by Kaspersky.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows check "World Wide Web Publishing Service" if it is running, because when you install IIS it has a service that auto. starts and listens 80, 443 port.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today, but the webserver's port was not already used.
Running the following commands in elevated terminal solved the problem.

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

I think it had something to do with local sql server running on docker, and the webserver not being able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Access Protection in Antivirus,

I faced same issue at last found the below logs from antivirus.

Blocked by Access Protection rule   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SVCHOST.EXE C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MCAFEE\VIRUSSCAN ENTERPRISE\MCCONSOL.EXE Common Standard Protection:Prevent termination of McAfee processes  Action blocked : Terminate
Blocked by port blocking rule   C:\USERS\username\APPDATA\LOCAL\PROGRAMS\PYTHON\PYTHON37-32\PYTHON.EXE  Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -ano | find ":80"
```

then `TASKKILL /F /PID 4032`

as rafee noor said, but this doesn't work when Port is being used by SYSTEM

[Port 80 is being used by SYSTEM (PID 4), what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that)

or

```
NET stop HTTP
```

this works in above case

Answer (score 0):

For those who have encountered this error while using `vscode` for `remote host`:

1. Open `Terminal` ( View -> Terminal ) or ( CTRL+ ` )
2. Click on tab `PORTS`
3. Delete the port that is allocated by remote host as shown in picture.

[image]

Now you can use the port.

Answer (score 0):

this worked. windows 11.
assign the port=3000 or any, manually in app.run()

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run( port=8080, debug=True)
```

then a window  appeared ,clicked allowed
i think flask server and web app both try to run on
a single port in my case 5000 ,this may be the reason
,so changing port worked.  i am not sure its true .

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours debugging in Docker network and adjusting Windows ports and settings, I found that **disconnecting** from the **VPN** solved the issue.

Answer (score -4):

I found a solution to solve this problem in Python.

go to c:\python27\ directory and rigtlcick python.exe and tab to compaitbility  and select the admin privilege option and apply the changes. Now you issue the command it allows to create the socket connection.

Comment: This is insecure as it runs *all* Python scripts with administrator privileges. Moreover, the question has had an accepted answer for several years.