# Python urllib2 cannot open localhost on alternate port (not 80)? Error 10013

Tags: python, error-handling, localhost, urllib2, httplib

Here is my **server.py**:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class TestRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.wfile.write("hello world at %s" % __file__)

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 10000), TestRequestHandler)
#server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 8888), TestRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Here is my **client.py**:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1:10000/')
handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = handle.read()
```

Then I start server.py, it works.

When I start client.py, I get this error on **Windows 7, Python 2.6**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\Forge\urllib-error\client.py", line 3, in <module>
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1161, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions>
```

When I open http://127.0.0.1:10000/ from a browser, it works. It means server is fine.

When I replace http://127.0.0.1:10000/ with http://127.0.0.1/ or http://127.0.0.1:80/ in client.py, everything works fine (this is another web server on port 80 - apache).

**What do I do wrong?**

**UPD:** Same error when I use this **client2.py**:

```
import urllib2
handle = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:10000/')
content = handle.read()
```

**UPD:** Problem solved. It was my firewall. When disabled, everything works. Stupid, stupid me. Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: Nice story after all. BTW, are to able to telnet to your server?.. Like this: `telnet localhost 10000`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [socket.error: \[Errno 10013\] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbi)

Comment: @Sergey Vasilyev stackoverflow is not a forum. Instead of marking the title as `[SOLVED]`, go ahead and answer your own question and accept the answer.

Comment: @phihag, that was my humble edit, and it was approved by a couple of folks of some 10K reputation. I cannot quickly find any references about this case in the SO FAQ, could you please point these out?..

Comment: @phihag thank you!.. Quite clear, not easily searchable :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The local firewall prevented the connection. When it's disabled, everything works.