# ipython notebook error (Errno: 10013)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed iPython and have all the dependencies for starting iPython notebook namely ipython.zmq, tornado, and math jax. I have python2.7-32bit installed on win7. I am able to run iPython, but when I type in `ipython --notebook` in cmd prompt, I get this:

```
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permission
```

By the way, I have mongoDB installed on my computer. I have read about this kind of error in the net that this means the port accessed by the program is already in use by another program. Could that be the problem? Kindly help me fix this.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb
According to http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html, you can manually specify the port for ipython-notebook with --port option, so it might be worth trying some different ports first of all.

Incidentally, isn't the syntax 'ipython notebook', rather than 'ipython --notebook'?