# What does the below error message mean?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, pydev

I'm trying out django with Eclipse's PyDev.

When I tried to start the server with runserver, I got the following message:

```
Performing system checks...System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 12, 2014 - 17:40:14
Django version 1.7, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Error: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its caccess permissions
```

Last line is an error message, which I don't understand.

Could anyone help explain?
I'm using `MySQL`.

Comment: Check firewall, maybe 8000 port is blocked, or you need to open it by yourself.

Comment: in what `OS` you run this?

Comment: @Hasan Ramezani: WinError explains what OS is it:)

Comment: @coldmind :), unfortunately i am not famillar wit windows things. take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb). this may help you