# Getting error while running command --> python ccm start on Cassandra cluster manager Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: sockets, websocket, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

Hi I somehow managed to install ccm on my windows machine.While running command --> python ccm start I get an error as

```
UnavailableSocketError("Inet address %s:%s is not available: %s" % (addr, port, msg)) ccmlib.common.UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:9042 is not available: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

My ccm is stored in this folder--->C:\ccm\ccm-master

Following are the steps I am doing with CCM :-

```
1.C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\ccm\ccm-master
```

I am creating a new cluster like this

```
2.C:\ccm\ccm-master>python ccm create test_cluster -v 2.0.9    
Current cluster is now: test_cluster
```

Adding 2 nodes to the test_cluster like this

```
3.C:\ccm\ccm-master>python ccm populate -n 2
```

I am checking the status like this

```
4.C:\ccm\ccm-master>python ccm status
Cluster: 'test_cluster'
-----------------------
node1: DOWN (Not initialized)
node2: DOWN (Not initialized)
```

as both the nodes are down , so I run this command to start cluster .

```
5.C:\ccm\ccm-master>python ccm start     
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "ccm", line 72, in <module>    
cmd.run()    
File "C:\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\cmds\cluster_cmds.py", line 492, in run    
profile_options=profile_options) is None:    
File "C:\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\cluster.py", line 249, in start    
p = node.start(update_pid=False, jvm_args=jvm_args, profile_options=profile_options)    
File "C:\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\node.py", line 434, in start    
common.check_socket_available(itf)    
File "C:\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\common.py", line 331, in check_socket_available    
raise UnavailableSocketError("Inet address %s:%s is not available: %s" % (addr, port, msg))    
ccmlib.common.UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:9042 is not available: [Errno 10013]    An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

So can anyone tell me why am I getting this error ?How I can make it work ? any additional settings are there , that I forgot to do ? Please provide valueable solution
Note- my firewall is off and antivirus is disabled still I get this error.

Comment: This is probably UAC related as documented in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb

Comment: --- @mikea or anyone ..a proper detailed solution would really help...

Comment: I posted a detailed answer on how to create a local multi-node Cassandra cluster on Windows 7 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34199571/181406