# 'WinError 10013' running Django on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, sockets

It has been almost a month since I got this problem, and I really appreciate your help. While trying to login in my Django Web App, i encounter OSError at /accounts/login/.I am able to login in 127.0.0.1:8000/admin, but not in the /accounts/login which produces the Error Code:

```
OSError at /accounts/login/
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
Exception Location: C:\Python35-32\lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 702
Python Executable:  C:\Python35-32\myvenv_python3\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Kaleab\\Desktop\\ecomstore',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy-1.1.7-py3.5-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\myvenv_python3\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python35-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Kaleab\\Desktop\\ecomstore',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\myvenv_python3\\Scripts\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\myvenv_python3\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Possible Causes and Solutions

1. Cause: Socket access needs administrative privilege.
   Attempted Solution:  •  Granted Administrator access to python.exe by navigating to the virtual environment. •  Navigate to CMD.exe , right click , properties, grant administrator privilege.
2. Cause: Port can be already used by another program. Attempted Solution: Checked the ports using TCPView windows program and see that the port 8000 is not used by another program.
3. Cause: Socket access blocked by Firewall and Antivirus. Attempted Solution: When I tried disabling Firewall and Antivirus, I get another error ConnectionRefusedError at accounts/login/ [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
4. Cause: Winsock has malfunctioned. Attempted Solution: Tried and successfully reset winsock, but this did not solve it either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb

Comment: @gliptak I saw that post, unfortunately did not solve my problem. I am not sure if it is a User Account Control (UAC) issue in Windows 8.1. Although I can run as Administrator, I am still denied socket permission. I have looked into cheking FIrewall and Antivirus , but to no avail.

Answer (score 16):

I will take running the server with different port as the answer, although I am not able to see port 8000 is used in stackoverflow suggested commands. Use: python manage.py runserver 8080.

Comment: Worked for me. However, it is quite strange to know that the port 8000 was not being used anywhere else. Regardless, this trick worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but don't know why it worked

Comment: It worked for me but I would like to know why a port might be used somewhere else all on a sudden.TIA

Comment: This worked for me as well, but I did not have anything on port 8000, very strange that it failed in the first place

Answer (score 5):

Changing the port worked for me, I was trying to run the django server.
Its not a firewall issue just type port in front of your command

python manage.py runserver **7000**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using a different port:

```
python manage.py runserver 9999
```

`9999` Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Since changing the port worked for @Kaleab, the problem may have been another process using that port.

I just found a Firefox process with a loopback connection from port 5000 to port 5000 (strange?).  Once I closed Firefox, I was able to start my Flask server without that error.

To find out which process is using the port, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows).

Comment: When I run netstat -a -b in my cmd, one of the lines was [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:8000              TIA-NEXCHMB1:0         LISTENING. I think my application was trying to use a port that was already being used, because I was attempting to run a django application on 8000. So I changed my port to 8080 and it woked

Answer (score 0):

run the command with port number 8080 as follows

python manage.py runserver 8080

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your computer and run
`python manage.py runserver`
or
`python manage.py runserver PORT_NUMBER`
or
`python manage.py runserver 8000`
or
`python manage.py runserver 8080`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have another process running that is using the port. Finding and killing the process will enable you to use the 8000 port.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Error Message due to my Antivirus App (Kaspersky). All i had to do was to assign `manage.py` in Kasperky < manage programms to `trustworthy`. I have a foreign version so `trustworthy` is a literal translation, maybe in the english version it is named different.