# Django admin site login error -"This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect."

Tags: python, django, web-applications, localhost

I am developing a web app using Django 3.0.1 and python 3.7 for my college's final year project. Whenever I try to login to the admin page in the local host in google chrome, link "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/" I got this error in the terminal
**GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2926**

and the ports that are started in XAMPP are:
** 80, 443(Apache), 3306(MySQL)**

**And in google chrome I get this error:**
"This site can’t be reached  127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

link of the error image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9VdU.png

I know this may not be due to wrong username and password. I have done lots of research on this topic but couldn't find a solution.

I have found that updating python version would solve this problem but haven't tried that one cause I have been developing other projects in the same version.

I have tried using other ports 8080, 9000 that also did not work.

So, if anyone can answer this problem it would help me a lot. And thankyou in advance.

Comment: How do you run  the django app? `python manage.py runserver`? Then the default port is 8000 and you should try: `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978096/winerror-10013-running-django-on-windows this link!

Comment: ok i will try that link too i use python manage.py runserver to run the program

Comment: Check if  DEBUG = False in settings.py. If it is set to False, Django won't accept any connections unless it is in ALLOWED_HOSTS. If so, try setting ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '127.0.0.1']

Comment: trying setting ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '127.0.0.1'] Also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

can you please share that error image? and try to run site on another port!

```
exec ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<your_port>
```

Comment: yes i have used python manage.py runserver to run the app and the actual url was http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ the url in the question was mistake.correcting right now

Comment: change port number to 9999 or any random number and try to run again

Comment: also in terminal i get this error "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2926 when trying http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Comment: this is the link to the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9VdU.png

Comment: link to the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9VdU.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command to

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 (WINDOWS)

or

> python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 (LINUX)

It will run on port 8080 you can check on 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: when trying python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 i got this error 
Error: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: didn't logged in on 127.0.0.1:8080 too

Comment: try with another port 8081 maybe. Your error says that Port 8080 has been used by another process. If it works don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: using port 8081 also did not work i have ports, 80, 443 (Apache), 3306(MySQL)  turned on in the xampp

Comment: Restart your system once and try again

Comment: i have tried that too. do you think that could be the problem in the router

Comment: I don't think that. open command prompt and type `netstat -ao |find /i "listening"` this command will help you to check the listening port. then choose a port apart from that..

Comment: i have ports, 80, 443 (Apache), 3306(MySQL) turned on in the xampp, Later i will try by using the port available given by this command netstat -ao |find /i "listening"

Answer (score 0):

After trying many processes that were available to me the project did not work. So, i uninstalled my python version 3.7 and installed python 3.8.7 which worked for me. But still i could not figure out the problem, but installing newer version worked for me.