# How can I fix WinError10013 in streamlit library when run it in cmd?

Tags: python, streamlit

- I using streamlit library of Python like this:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.write("""
# My First App
Hello *world!*         
""")

df = pd.read_csv("data\customer_booking.csv",  encoding="ISO-8859-1")
st.line_chart(df["purchase_lead"])
```

- But after used cmd:
  `streamlit run main.py`
- It showed the WinError10013:
  "PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions".

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978096/winerror-10013-running-django-on-windows), it seems like changing the port might resolve the issue – you can do so by adding the following to a `.streamlit/config.toml` file ([related doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration)):

```
[server]
port = 80
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a firewall error. Make sure you're allowing Python to go through the firewall, and that nothing is using the same port as the one you are using for Streamlit.