# Python accessing parent variable inside nested function

Tags: python

```
def download(self):
    ftp = self.connect()
    try:
        size = ftp.size(filename=self.filename)
        print "Total size of {filename} is {size}".format(filename=self.filename, size=size)
        written_till_now = 0
        def handle(bytes):
            f.write(bytes)
            print "written bytes: {}".format(bytes)

        with open(self.filename, 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(self.filename), handle)
    except (socket.error, error_perm) as e:
        raise DownloaderException("Error in downloading file {filename}: {message}".format(filename=self.filename, message=str(e)))
    except EOFError as e:
        print "file {filename} downloaded successfully".format(filename=self.filename)
```

I want to keep track of the amount of data i've currently downloaded and later do some additional stuff also for every stream of data i download.

I created a `handle` function inside the `download` function.

Python ftblip.retrbinary provides the data to the given callback. In my case `handle` but somehow it is not executing.

Also I doubt i am not understanding the scope of variables when it comes to nested functions. In my understanding I can use variable defined in parent scope in the child scope as long as i am not modifying them.But in this case `f` is a object and i am not modifying it rather calling its method `write`. Please correct me if i am missing something.

Comment: it doesn't from outside too.

Comment: I am putting it insie because later i will build a progressbar which will take. so the variable ```written_till_now``` i will access and increment

Comment: I think its because i am not even getting a single byte. It throws exception o connection refused after a while.

Comment: I would put it inside the `with` block because you are using `f` variable which is defined there.

Comment: are you able to get a successful ftp connection ? try to print something before and after `ftp = self.connect()` , if not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779304/5585424) might help

Comment: Let me update my question so it becomes more relevant

Comment: @AnkushRathi That line is okay because it prints my message  `Total size of abc.csv is 88009`

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handle` function doesn't have access to the scoped `f` variable. Instead you can pass the open file directly to `handle`.

```
def handle(fp, bytes):
    fp.write(bytes)
    print "written bytes: {}".format(bytes)

with open(self.filename, 'wb') as f:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(self.filename), lambda b: handle(f, b))
```

Comment: ```lambda b:``` means that the ftp will use the ```b``` variable ?

Comment: It means that the  callback function takes a single argument, which we call `b`.