# Causes of TCPClient socket error 0x80004005

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

**"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"**

OK I know this problem has occurred many times before on S.O., but I cannot find a solution. Here is my question: what are possible causes of this.

Points:

- Happens irrespective of firewall
- Ports are open
- Destination is open and connections have been working in the past
- Since working connections, no changes to firewalls or virus scanners, can rule those out.
- Running as administrative user
- Source port is 23876
- Destination port is variable, depends on detected client from another source
- Windows 8.1

One more point - this error also happened after porting to .NET Core.

The only change is that I am trying to share ports but I can't see the connection between that and the error.The code to connect is

```
 client = new TcpClient();
                         client.Client.SetSocketOption(
                             SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                         client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 0);
                         client.Client.Bind(ipLocalEndPoint);
                         client.Client.Connect(ep);
```

where the local endpoint is reused.

What are the possible causes of this error? It is happening on every BIND call.

Comment: What port number are you trying to open? What access level (admin, standard user) is your code executing under? What operating system? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2778840/62576) for at least one reason that information is relevant to add to your post.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks Ken, it's all admin mode. Adding info now.

Answer (score 0):

OK this all turned out to be me being incredibly stupid.

What I had done, and forgotten I had done, is establish a TcpListener on the same port, with this code `_tcpListener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;` not working as I expected.