# Problem with `python manage.py runserver` command An attempt was made to access a socket

Tags: python, django, powershell, virtual-environment

I have an issue which says `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`. This issue is appearing when I use `python manage.py` command to run the server. 
Here is a picture with the problem [image: Capture.jpg]. Give some advice, tutorial or anything which could help me to fix it.

Comment: The error message suggests a solution. Also, post a text, not picture.

Comment: [This link might help you. Check out this.][link] [link]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb

Comment: if you are in local change your port python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001 and open it. **or** restart your system.

Comment: In my `settings.py` file
```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8001',
    }
}
```
and i it give this error 
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 8001?

Comment: Your postgres settings should probably be `'HOST' : 'localhost', 'PORT':''`