# Python 3.7.5 - snmplib - SMTP method is showing error

Tags: python, email, smtp, python-3.7, smtplib

I am trying to write a script which can send email from my gmail account. However I am getting error mentioned below. I am using windows10 64bit.
It looks like a SSL error but unable to find any solution for this -

```
import smtplib
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  File "C:\Users\SDE44\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\SDE44\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\SDE44\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\SDE44\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\SDE44\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**
```

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb

Comment: This port is not working it seems
C:\>netstat -na|findstr 587

C:\>