# Django- [WinError 10013]

Tags: python, django

I have started to learn Django and I am using my Employer's laptop, when I execute `python manage.py runserver` in Anaconda prompt, I am getting the following error, Thanks in Advance for any help or suggestion.

````
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 11, 2020 - 09:08:16
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Error: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.error: \[Errno 10013\] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb)

Comment: try to run on a different port like `127.0.0.1:7000`