# how to resolve this Flask application run.py Error

Tags: python, error-handling, web-applications

```
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\CSS3\harward\files\src2\variables0>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main    
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,`enter code here`
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 967, in main 
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None) 
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main   
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 852, in run_command
    run_simple(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 996, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 847, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason, but I wanted to stress that: "Flask is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment."

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in the virtual environment, so this is what I did:

1. I deactivated virtualenv and installed flask there
2. I activated the virtualenv and installed flask again and it worked.
   I faced this on windows10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).