# PermissionError with smtplib python

Tags: python, smtplib, permissionerror

I have been experimenting with smptlib and am trying to sen a email to somebody. Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
my_email = "sender_email@gmail.com"
my_password = "password1234"
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=my_password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="receiver_email@gmail.com", msg="Hello")
connection.quit()
```

The sender's email, sender's password, and receiver's email are not valid, for privacy reasons. I do, however keep getting this error:

`PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

It may help you to know that I am using the latest version of PyCharm IDE and the latest version of smtplib. My question is: Why am I continually getting this error?

I tried fiddling around, and I think that the code:

`connection = smtplib.SMTP("smpt.gmail.com")`

was the problem. I think. I also have tried putting in examples and other people's code, but I get the same `PermissionError` as always.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.error: \[Errno 10013\] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778840/socket-error-errno-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forb)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But thanks!

Comment: It is possible that gmail doesn't support the connection type that you are trying. Please do an SSL connection instead using the following command `connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)`. Also this webpage has a tutorial on how to send email using gmail in Python: https://mailtrap.io/blog/python-send-email-gmail/