# python socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, sockets, operating-system

I got this error message with the following python code:

```
TesterSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
TesterSocket.bind((host, port))
```

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes Python socket error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550032/what-causes-python-socket-error)